# Identification of this spider?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology

I find these in forests in Oregon, western half, though they're probably on the eastern half as well. They live under pieces of wood and bark, and have a small web across the ground. Mine will eat crickets, but I think they eat carpenter ants, termites, and maybe pillbugs/sowbugs. It seems about an inch long, red on the thorax and legs, and dark grey and slightly hairy on the abdomen. The closest to this spider I've found is sowbug killers -- they're in my backyard, but they're smaller then this spider and also are a light tan on a hairless abdomen, with lighter colored legs. The fangs also seem different shapes but I'm not sure about that.

[image: Spider 1]
[image: Spider 2]
[image: Spider 3]
[image: Spider 4]

Comment: Thanks for getting the images up there, I still can't figure out how to do it. Is there a way on mobile?

Comment: There is on iPhone at least, I'm not sure on other platforms.  You can always type up the markup manually (though it is a little cumbersome on mobile): `![an image](http://example.com/image)`

Comment: I thought it was the woodlouse spider too which is why I posted an answer but I am unsure now since you already suggested it. It should belong to the genus Dysdera though

Comment: Oregon has over 500 spiders so its hard to identify which one this is

Answer (score 6):

This is very likely a species in the [Amaurobiidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaurobiidae) superfamily, and I agree appears to be ***Callobius severus*** (the **hackled-band weaver** or the **hackledmesh weaver**).

[image]

<sup>Source: [Bugguide.net](http://bugguide.net/images/raw/V08/Q10/V08Q105QY0VQHS9QRS5KY0AQC0BQAK8KCKUQB08QV0HKBK5KCKMK30VQVK9QJ08KY08QNKQKC0PQZS.jpg)</sup>

[image]

<sup>Source: [Kyron Basu 2012](http://bugguide.net/node/view/640549)</sup>

[Moldenke et al. 1987](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.514.3279&rep=rep1&type=pdf) provide a key to spiders of the Pacific Northwest. Importantly, they note:

> adult genitalia are necessary for identifying species and separating
> *Callobius* from *Amaurobius*.

- For example, here is a picture of [***Amaurobius ferox***](http://www.spiders.us/species/amaurobius-ferox/) (Hackledmesh Weaver)

[image: Amaurobius ferox]

<sup>© [Danny Steaven 2008](http://www.spiders.us/image/amaurobius-ferox-4/)</sup>

- I've seen numerous sites conflate this species with *C severus* and actually I've seen sources that identify them both as the "*Hackledmesh Weaver*".

So although the OP's specimen *strongly* resembles *Callobius severus*, a scope is necessary to truly identify to species. This [Penn State page](http://ento.psu.edu/extension/factsheets/hackledmesh-weavers) provides good information regarding these similar looking species in the superfamily.

> *Callobius* and *Amaurobius* species have similar life histories and behaviors. They are most often found in damp locations under bark, leaf litter, and stones, as well as in woodpiles and other protected areas.

[Stephen Ellis Lew (2011)](http://digitalassets.lib.berkeley.edu/etd/ucb/text/Lew_berkeley_0028E_11522.pdf)  produced an atlas to the genitalic morphology of the *Callobius* genus, and he proposed a morphological diagnosis that is more consistent with principles of homology than those previously in use. [See the link for his dissertation on the subject].

#### Callobius severus

**Description**:

- Cephalothorax and legs = reddish to dark brown [[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaurobiidae)].
- Abdomen = dark to light grey with fine hairs; often with large, bilaterally mirrored paler spots.

**Ecology:**

- Nesting woodland species commonly seen in the Pacific Northwest
- [McIver et al. (1990)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:PjarsOooYpwJ:and.lternet.edu/lter/pubs/pdf/pub1126.pdf+&cd=8&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) suggests that this species of spider is one of many that is characteristic of young forests.

**Is it Dangerous?**:

- Not according to this [Penn state website](http://ento.psu.edu/extension/factsheets/hackledmesh-weavers):

> The one verified record of a bite by an immature Callobius species resulted in pain, itching, swelling, redness, and nausea.

- [Vetter & Antonelli](https://puyallup.wsu.edu/plantclinic/wp-content/uploads/sites/408/2015/02/PLS-116-How-to-Identify-or-Misidentify-the-Hobo-Spider.pdf) provide evidence for how to differentiate this species from the "more dangerous" hobo spider.

  [image]

> in the side view, the palp of *Callobius* males has large, conspicuous, pointed projections (Fig. 7).

Answer (score 4):

It look like *Callobius severus* to me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above that the spider is probably Callobius severus, especially since you found the spider in a forest in Oregon.
[image: spider]

The spider in found in parts of the United States and Canada with nests most widespread in the [U.S. state of Washington](http://pep.wsu.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2015/05/PLS116_1.pdf) and the states bordering Washington, making them most common in America's [Pacific Northwest region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Northwest).